# Show/hide multiple images in sequence with JS

Tags: javascript

I have working code for a) clicking a button, b) displaying an image for n ms, c) then hide it:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<p><b>Display Image </b></p>
<p>Click on button to display the image.</p>
<!-- button -->
<button id="btnId1">100 ms</button>
<!-- image to hide and show -->
<img src="img/img-a.jpg" alt="" id="imageID1" width="300" height="300" style="display: none" />

<script>

// add click event to button
    document.getElementById("btnId1").addEventListener('click', function() {
        //show image
        document.getElementById('imageID1').style.display='block';
        // hide image after 100 ms.
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById('imageID1').style.display='none';
        }, 100);
    });

</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to do is

a) Click the button,
b) display + hide **several** .jpg images **in sequence**, and
c) have the control for each image on how long to display it

I have looked through similar topics/posts but haven't found what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for any input,
-- JW

Comment: Do you mean do like a slide show for `imageID1`?

Comment: search `carousel in js` and your find plenty of resources

Comment: @Johnny Mopp Yes, I guess that would apply as long as I have full control over what images to use and the ability to set individual visibility time (ms).

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks - will look into it!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp To clarify: I want to use multiple images like imageID1, imageID2, imageID3, etc.